# Return the most recent record from ElasticSearch index

Tags: elasticsearch

I would like to return the most recent record (top 1) from ElasticSearch index similar to the sql query below;

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 Id, name, title 
FROM MyTable 
ORDER BY Date DESC;
```

Can this be done?

Comment: if you are using the `python` `elasticsearch` modules: [use this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52785077/52074)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Do you have [_timestamp](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) enabled in your doc mapping?

```
{
    "doctype": {
        "_timestamp": {
            "enabled": "true",
            "store": "yes"
        },
        "properties": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

You can check your mapping here:

```
http://localhost:9200/_all/_mapping
```

If so I think this might work to get most recent:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": 1,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: At least with the client I use (Chrome "Advanced REST Client" extension), I had to put the "1" of '"size": 1' in double-quotes for it to take effect.

Comment: What's the difference between using the _timestamp field and using a custom timestamp field?

Comment: @castarco, when enabled, _timestamp was generated automatically for you so you could use it, like mconlin suggested, instead of adding your own. However, since 2.0.0-beta2, _timestamp was deprecated, so you should go with your own timestamp after all :)
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html

Comment: `_timestamp` didn't work for me. but `@timestamp` did.

Comment: I'm getting below error: 
`org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: Mapping definition for [_timestamp] has unsupported parameters:  [store : yes]`

Comment: Yeah I'm using elasticsearch py and get that error too. The query worked for me via curl directly to es but  using the py client you have to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52785077/52074).

Answer (score 14):

For information purpose, _timestamp is now deprecated since 2.0.0-beta2.
Use [`date`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) type in your mapping.

A simple date mapping JSON from [`date`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/date.html) datatype doc:

```
{
  "mappings": {
     "my_type": {
        "properties": {
          "date": {
          "type": "date" 
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You can also add a `format` field in `date`:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "my_type": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss||yyyy-MM-dd||epoch_millis"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

Get the Last ID using by date (with out time stamp)

> **Sample URL** : http://localhost:9200/deal/dealsdetails/
>   **Method** : POST

Query :

```
{
  "fields": ["_id"],
  "sort": [{
      "created_date": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    },
    {
      "_score": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

result:

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 9,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": [{
      "_index": "deal",
      "_type": "dealsdetails",
      "_id": "10",
      "_score": 1,
      "sort": [
        1478266145174,
        1
      ]
    }]
  }
}
```

Comment: Good alternative if you have a date you can reference in your doc mapping but its not the es timestamp. I couldn't get it to work with elasticsearch py so I will just use my modified_on doc date. I would be skeptical to use created date as that does not change on doc updates.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [sort](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html) on date field and [size=1](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-from-size.html) parameter.
Does it help?

Comment: How can we do if we are looking for the last document possessing a wanted first level attribute ?
because in some cases I have in my index/document query results : 
_registered : { date : 2016-03-18, .....
_pending: { date: 2016-03-16, ...

It will retrieve me only the _register document, because its the newer, but when I try to parse _pending.<attribute> it fails because of the key not being the excpected one. Can we specify this in a search query ? thanks !

Comment: no idea. I don't understand. You should me be open a new discussion with an example?

Comment: No this doesn't help. An example would have been worth a thousand webqueries.

Answer (score 6):

Since this question was originally asked and answered, some of the inner-workings of Elasticsearch have changed, particularly around timestamps. Here is a full example showing how to query for single latest record. Tested on ES 6/7.

1) Tell Elasticsearch to treat `timestamp` field as the timestamp

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/my_index?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"mappings":{"message":{"properties":{"timestamp":{"type":"date"}}}}}'
```

2) Put some test data into the index

```
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/my_index/message/1" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "timestamp" : "2019-08-02T03:00:00Z", "message" : "hello world" }'
curl -XPOST "localhost:9200/my_index/message/2" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "timestamp" : "2019-08-02T04:00:00Z", "message" : "bye world" }'
```

3) Query for the latest record

```
curl -X POST "localhost:9200/my_index/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"query": {"match_all": {}},"size": 1,"sort": [{"timestamp": {"order": "desc"}}]}'
```

4) Expected results

```
{
   "took":0,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "skipped":0,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":2,
      "max_score":null,
      "hits":[
         {
            "_index":"my_index",
            "_type":"message",
            "_id":"2",
            "_score":null,
            "_source":{
               "timestamp":"2019-08-02T04:00:00Z",
               "message":"bye world"
            },
            "sort":[
               1564718400000
            ]
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using python elasticsearch5 module or curl:

1. make sure each document that gets inserted has

   - a timestamp field that is type datetime
   - and you are monotonically increasing the timestamp value for each document
2. from python you do

   ```
   es = elasticsearch5.Elasticsearch('my_host:my_port')
   es.search(
       index='my_index', 
       size=1,
       sort='my_timestamp:desc'
       )
   ```

If your documents are not inserted with any field that is of type datetime, then I don't believe you can get the N "most recent".

Answer (score 3):

I used `@timestamp` instead of `_timestamp`

```
{
    'size' : 1,
    'query': {
        'match_all' : {}
            },
    "sort" : [{"@timestamp":{"order": "desc"}}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the _timestamp didn't work out for me,

this query does work for me:

(as in mconlin's answer)

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "size": "1",
  "sort": [
    {
      "@timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Could be trivial but the _timestamp answer didn't gave an error but not a good result either...

Hope to help someone...

(kibana/elastic 5.0.4)

S.