# How can I get last arrived document ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a cluster with documents that contains timestamp field.

How can i request for the last arrived of them?

Comment: You can't with only one query. You need two: get the max date and then another query with your max date.

Comment: I'm afraid i can't understand you. I have a 6 documents, each have timestamp field. I want get one of them - the last arrived document.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return the most recent record from ElasticSearch index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723379/return-the-most-recent-record-from-elasticsearch-index)

Comment: if using python elasticsearch module, https://stackoverflow.com/a/52785077/52074

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A query like the one below should do the trick. It'll get you the one document with the latest date in the `timestamp` field.

```
{
  "size": 1,
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "sort": {
    "timestamp": "desc"
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this query runs through ALL ES. 
filtering should be great!

Comment: @confiq Of course, you can add a range query from `now-5m` (or more minutes depending on the ingestion rate) to `now` on the `timestamp` field in order to select less documents. But the thing is that by default each shard will return a single document (size: 1)  to the coordinating node and the coordinating node will return only one of those (i.e. the one ranked according to the most recent timestamp).